# DynamoDB: Create Table with keytype for nested json using Boto3

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to create a new table in `DynamoDB` using my data format from `MongoDB`. I know how to create basic tables and update data, however, for nested `JSON` body I am *unable to create KeySchema* as I am new to this.

**My JSON example:**

```
{
    'Name':"fresco"
    'Tags':{
        'Genre':'Jazz'
        'Albums':['aa','bb''cc']}
    'Year:'2009
}
```

I am using boto3 and I know how to connect with AWS, I just need some help with keyschema for this JSON body. Also, I've read about [*Map* attribute](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.NamingRulesDataTypes.html#HowItWorks.DataTypes) from AWS docs but there was no implementation for that.

**My Code:**

```
import boto3
dynamodb =boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.create_table(
    TableName = 'newTable'
    KeySchema = [
    {
        'AttributeName': 'Name',
        'KeyType': 'Hash'
    },
    {
        'AttributeName': 'Tags',
        'KeyType': 'Hash'
    },
    {
        'AttributeName': 'Year',
        'KeyType': 'Hash'
    }

    ],

    AttributeDefinitions=[
    {
        'AttributeName': 'Name',
        'AttributeType': 'S'
    },
    {
        'AttributeName': 'Tags',
        'AttributeType': #dont know what to put in here.
    },
    {
        'AttributeName': 'Year',
        'AttributeType': 'N'
    },


    ],

    ProvisionedThroughput ={
    'ReadCapacityUnits': 5,
    'WriteCapacityUnits': 5

    }

)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In DynamoDB you can only have one partition key or one partition key + one sort key. And you also have limits on the length of your key too - so tags may not be the best fit. Best to read the [developer docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.CoreComponents.html#HowItWorks.CoreComponents.PrimaryKey).

Comment: Okay, I got that, So there is any way to provide nested json via python?

Comment: Yes. Look at [maps (M) in here][1]. And use the DynamoDB console to paste in JSON and get a feel for what special JSON DynamoDB expects.


  [1]: https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.put_item

Comment: Thanks, found it now.